# I made a payment for Form 1040-ES via IRS.gov/payments. Do I have to fill any form in addition to that?

Tags: united-states, taxes, irs, online-payment, estimated-taxes

I made a payment for [Form 1040-ES](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-1040-es) via https://www.irs.gov/payments. Do I have to fill any form in addition to that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No.** If you make a payment online you're done. The only other form you'd use for an estimated tax payment is the Form 1040-ES payment voucher, and they say:

> File only if you are making a payment of estimated tax by check or money order.